# How to concatenate a string to each element of a possible empty character vector?

Tags: r

The base `R` functions `paste` and `paste0` allow to concatenate strings (called "characters" in `R`).

For example:

```r
new_people <- c(" R. A. Becker", "J. M. Chambers", "A. R. Wilks")
paste0("Hello ", new_people, "!")
# [1] "Hello  R. A. Becker!"  "Hello J. M. Chambers!" "Hello A. R. Wilks!"
```

However, if one the arguments is of length zero (`character()`), it behaves inconsistent and unexpected:

```r
new_people <- character()
paste0("Hello ", new_people, "!")
# [1] "Hello !"
```

This behavior is described (but not motivated) in `?paste`:

> Vector arguments are recycled as needed, with zero-length arguments being recycled to "".
>   [...]
>   **Value:**
>   A character vector of the concatenated values. This will be of length zero if all the objects are, unless collapse is non-NULL in which case it is a single empty string.

If you do not find it "inconsistent" yet, imagine an answer to [Equivalent of R's paste command for vector of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046408/equivalent-of-rs-paste-command-for-vector-of-numbers-in-python) that would *really* reproduce `paste`'s behavior.

To avoid cluttering of my code I was searching for an alternative function or parameter for `paste` that would only recycle length 1 arguments. – Unfortunately, unsuccessfully. Not even the `str_c` function in @hadley's `stringr` package provides such behavior.

**Is there an alternative to paste (and paste0) that behaves consistent w.r.t. zero length arguments (i.e. returns a zero length character vector in that case and an empty string if `collapse` is not `NULL`)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OUTDATED (still valid for R <4.0.1):

---

While writing this question, I found an almost satisfying answer:

```r
new_people <- c(" R. A. Becker", "J. M. Chambers", "A. R. Wilks")
sprintf("Hello %s!", new_people)
# [1] "Hello  R. A. Becker!"  "Hello J. M. Chambers!" "Hello A. R. Wilks!"   

new_people <- character()
sprintf("Hello %s!", new_people)
# character(0)
```

This, however, lacks the nice linkage between the variables and their position in the string that `paste` has and requires an additional surrounding `paste(..., collapse="")` if one wants to smush the strings together.

Answer (score 2):

In R 4.0.1 a new argument `recycle0` was introduced to `paste` and `paste0` (see [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.0.1/NEWS.R-4.0.1.html)) that does just that:

```
new_people <- character()
paste0("Hello ", new_people, "!", recycle0 = TRUE)
# character(0)
```

It also plays nicely with `collapse=TRUE`:

```r
new_people <- character()
paste0("Hello ", new_people, "!", collapse = "\n", recycle0 = TRUE)
# ""
```

Currently the default is `FASLE`, I hope it will be gracefully changed to `TRUE` some day in the not too far future.