# concatenate two sting columns - python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X" : ["2017-12-17","2017-12-18","2017-12-19"],
                  "Y": ["F","W","Q"]})
```

And I'm looking for the `key` column:

```
           X    Y            key
0   2017-12-17  F   2017-12-17_F  
1   2017-12-18  W   2017-12-18_W
2   2017-12-19  Q   2017-12-19_Q
```

I have tried [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653208/paste0-like-function-in-python-for-multiple-strings),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972410/pandas-combine-two-columns-in-a-dataframe),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns), and the best solution is (for speed, as they are near 1 million rows):

```
df.assign(key=[str(x) + "_" + y for x, y in zip(df["X"], df["Y"])])
```

And it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'str'
```

Why?

Comment: It would seem that one of the values is not of type `str`. using the sample code you provide, all are strings. But perhaps your actual data is not.

Comment: figure out which, and convert to string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python/35780962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `X` column is not string as posted, but `TimeStamp`. Anyway, you can try:

```
df['key'] = df.X.astype(str) + '_' + df.Y.astype(str)
```